# Extract n-tupels from a list of tupels in python

Tags: python

I got a list of tuples after some calcualtions, which contains `[(str, str, float), (...), ...]` format:

```
output: [('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739792547374054),
         ('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739792718209167),
         ('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739793368940086),
         ('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.10266894735114324),
         ('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.1026689508485586),
         ('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.10873575415245394),
         ('inputData_3', 'targetData_1', 0.1464233452565107),
         ('inputData_3', 'targetData_1', 0.14642335418508975),
         ('inputData_3', 'targetData_1', 0.14642336077619336),
         ('inputData_1', 'targetData_1', 0.1561837827131314),
         ('inputData_1', 'targetData_1', 0.15618378709179737),
         ('inputData_1', 'targetData_1', 0.15618379092496212)]
```

The list is sorted using float as key-value`sorted(meanScores, key=lambda tup: tup[2])` and as you see, every tuple is repeated three times.

How I can extract only three tupels (if the list contains at least three tupels) with smallest float values from the whole list and without repeating it?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

The order of repeated tupels can be also listed differently like:

```
output: [('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739792547374054),
         ('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.1026689508485586),
         ('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739793368940086),
         ('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.10266894735114324),
         ('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.10873575415245394),
         ('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739792718209167),
         ...]
```

Comment: Hint: `itertools.groupby`...

Comment: Your description is a bit lacking: If you don't have at least three elements, you can not extract three elements, so that part of your description is redundant. A precise description is necessary to define an algorithm that does the right thing though.

Comment: If your list is sorted by `tup[2]`, and you want the three tuples with the lowest value for `tup[2]`, that's just `output[:3]`. If that's not what you want, what _is_ what you want?

Comment: `output[:3]` gives `[('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739792547374054),
         ('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739792718209167),
         ('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739793368940086)]` so same tupels with repeating. But correct output should be `[('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739792547374054), ('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.10266894735114324), ('inputData_3', 'targetData_1', 0.1464233452565107)] `

Answer (score 2):

Note sure to understand what you want but here is what I understand: you have a list of tuples composed of two strings and a float value. You want to group the consecutive tuples which strings are equals, and find the tuple which float value is the minimum.

If your tuples are sorted, you can use `itertools.groupby` to do the grouping and `min` to find the minimum value:

```
output= [('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739792547374054),
         ('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739792718209167),
         ('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739793368940086),
         ('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.10266894735114324),
         ('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.1026689508485586),
         ('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.10873575415245394),
         ('inputData_3', 'targetData_1', 0.1464233452565107),
         ('inputData_3', 'targetData_1', 0.14642335418508975),
         ('inputData_3', 'targetData_1', 0.14642336077619336),
         ('inputData_1', 'targetData_1', 0.1561837827131314),
         ('inputData_1', 'targetData_1', 0.15618378709179737),
         ('inputData_1', 'targetData_1', 0.15618379092496212)]

# sort is sorted, group by input/target
import itertools

for key, group in itertools.groupby(output, key=lambda t: t[:2]):
    tmin = min(group, key=lambda t: t[2])
    print(tmin)
```

You get:

```
('inputData_4', 'targetData_1', 0.09739792547374054)
('inputData_2', 'targetData_1', 0.10266894735114324)
('inputData_3', 'targetData_1', 0.1464233452565107)
('inputData_1', 'targetData_1', 0.1561837827131314)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution gives duplicate outputs if list of tupel is long.

Comment: This is not a question of size. You need to sort your tuples before grouping.